# PyDev - unittest fails with ImportError

Tags: python, eclipse, unit-testing, pydev, python-import

My PyDev (Eclipse Oxygen) project (using Python 3.5 on Xubuntu 16.04) consists of 3 packages:

- `ylang` - this is where most of my code is and is the core of the project
- `tkinter_integration` - offers easy way to integrate `ylang` in Tkinter
- `tests` - contains unit tests for both `ylang` and `tkinter_integration`

The folder structure is

```
YLanguage---+
            |
            +--ylang--+
            |         |
            |         +--ylang.py (contains YParser with its load_file() member function)
            |
            |
            +--tkinter_integration--+
            |                       |
            |                       +-- ...
            |
            +--tests--+
                      |
                      +--load_file.py (contains TestLoadFile with its testLoadInvalid() member function)
                      |
                      +-- ...
```

I added a unit test using the PyDev unit test wizard (for unit test modules you can pick between **Module: Unittest** and **Module: Unittest with setUp and tearDown**; I selected the first).

The test module looks like this:

```
import unittest

class TestLoadFile(unittest.TestCase):

    def testLoadInvalid(self):
        from ylang import YParser

        yp = YParser()
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, yp.load_file(None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #import sys;sys.argv = ['', 'TestLoadFile.testLoadInvalid']
    unittest.main()
```

When I run the test I get

> **ERROR**: testLoadInvalid (tests.load_file.TestLoadFile)
>
> ---
>
> `"/home/user/workspace/YLanguage/tests/load_file.py"`, line 12, in
>   testLoadInvalid
>
> ```
> `from ylang import YParser` ImportError: cannot import name 'YParser'Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> ```

I have made sure the respective subdirectories are part of `PYTHONPATH` for my project inside the **PyDev - PYTHONPATH** properties (**Source folders**):

- `/${PROJECT_DIR_NAME}`
- `/${PROJECT_DIR_NAME}/ylang`
- `/${PROJECT_DIR_NAME}/tkinter_integration`
- `/${PROJECT_DIR_NAME}/tests`

All packages have been created using PyDev wizard and have `__init__.py`  files in them so they should be perceived actual packages.

Here is the output from `sys.path` as requested in the comments:

> ['/home/user/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev_5.9.0.201708101613/pysrc',
>   **'/home/user/workspace/YLanguage'**,
>   **'/home/user/workspace/YLanguage/ylang'**,
>   **'/home/user/workspace/YLanguage/tkinter_integration'**,
>   **'/home/user/workspace/YLanguage/tests'**, '/usr/lib/python3.5',
>   '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-i386-linux-gnu',
>   '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
>   '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages',
>   '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python35.zip',
>   **'/home/user/workspace/YLanguage'**]

Comment: According to the folder structure from the question, `YParser`'s "*FQDN*" is: `YLanguage.lib.yparser.YParser` (no `ygdl` involved).

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the type. It's `ylang` (both the package and the module in it) where `YParser` is located. I thought that if I added `ylang` (package) to the `PYTHONPATH` it should automatically allow me to call `from ylang import ...`.

Comment: With _.../YLanguage/ylang_ folder in _${PYTHONPATH}_, the import should work (assuming there's an _\_\_init\_\_.py(c)_ file next to _ylang.py_).

Comment: I've added the properties (1:1 from the PyDev project) at the end. Unless I'm mistaken it seems that everything is in there.

Comment: Why don't you add the line `print(sys.path)` before the faulty one?

Comment: I actually did that already but didn't find anything missing. Updated comment at the end. The only strange thing is that the project's root folder is added twice.